# Синтаксическая роль слова "что" в предложении

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем является слово "что" в предложении?
Какую синтаксическую роль оно выполняет?

***Что*** это было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем является слово "что" в предложении?
>
> Какую синтаксическую роль оно выполняет?

Ту же, что и в предложении ***"Что это?"***

Здесь ЭТО — подлежащее, ЧТО — сказуемое, БЫЛО — глагол-связка, входящая в состав сказуемого.

***Что это было? —  Это был экзамен.***

ЭТО в обоих предложениях —  **подлежащее**.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

ЧТО — вопросительное местоимение в роли подлежащего, ср.: *что было?*

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

**Что** это **было?**   Это был гром.

**БЫЛО ЧТО** — составное именное сказуемое, **ЭТО** — подлежащее.

Сравнить: Это что?  Это (есть) книга.